# Is there an method in Rails3 / ruby gem, which maps status codes to messages?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, render, http-status-codes

Such as

```
200 => Found
403 => Not authorized
404 => Not found
```

I'm guessing Rails 3 already has this functionality as you can pass a hash to `render :status => :not_found`, I just can't find the method to do it the other way. If not does anyone know of a gem which can do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES[200]
=> "OK"
irb(main):002:0> Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES[403]
=> "Forbidden"
irb(main):003:0> Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES[404]
=> "Not Found"
```

or

```
irb(main):004:0> Rack::Utils.status_code(:ok)
=> 200
irb(main):005:0> Rack::Utils.status_code(:forbidden)
=> 403
irb(main):006:0> Rack::Utils.status_code(:not_found)
=> 404
```

Comment: List of the [HTTP status codes](https://github.com/chneukirchen/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L397) and [how to use a symbol for the defined codes](https://github.com/chneukirchen/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L454)

Comment: Updated link for the HTTP status codes of the last comment: https://github.com/chneukirchen/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L477-530